'Some people' and 'Others' and their relation in context of being majority/minority/equal
When there is a question that is about viewpoints of people for instance, and the answer comes in format like:

Some people ...
Others ...

This generally gives me feeling that the first is minority and second is a majority, am I wrong to assume this?
When I replace 'Some people' with

The most people - I immediately know the relation to Others
Many people - I don't know the exact number but here I would guess it could be 50/50


You have two separate questions. Some people think x; others think y. There is no minority/majority there. Many people in the room disagreed. [there were 20 people in the room]. That does not mean 50/50/ It's indeterminate.

It's loose language, and probably deliberately so. It could be 2.8% and 2.9% of the population or sample, but giving the exact figures would not really promote the views in question.

Yes, you are wrong to assume that. Some and others just means one group and another group, with no implications as to the size of those groups.
